# Unable to load AWS credentials from the /AwsCredentials.properties file on the classpath

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

Using this code for setting the class path

```
AWSCredentialsProvider credentialsProvider = new ClasspathPropertiesFileCredentialsProvider();
ec2 = new AmazonEC2Client(credentialsProvider);
```

Below is the format for AwsCredentials.properties file

```
# Fill in your AWS Access Key ID and Secret Access Key
# http://aws.amazon.com/security-credentials
accessKey = keyHere
secretKey = secretKeyHere
```

Below is the exception I am getting

```
Exception in thread "main" com.amazonaws.AmazonClientException: Unable to load AWS credentials from the /AwsCredentials.properties file on the classpath

    at com.amazonaws.auth.ClasspathPropertiesFileCredentialsProvider.getCredentials(ClasspathPropertiesFileCredentialsProvider.java:81)
    at com.amazonaws.services.ec2.AmazonEC2Client.invoke(AmazonEC2Client.java:8359)
```

Comment: can you describe your directory structure ?  Where is your .properties file ?

Comment: was the OP file format incorrect? Below answers say the key names use snake_case, not camelCase.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You are getting this exception because your AWS SDK is unable to load your credentials.
What you should do is goto Preferences then goto AWS and add your secret key and access key. So that your project can retrieve both keys.

Comment: I can't find "Preferences" and "AWS" to add key. Can you help me?

Comment: @iForests  https://console.aws.amazon.com/iam/home?region=us-east-2#/security_credential

Comment: This would only work if you have access to IAM. The issue is the majority of people working on AWS do not have the access due to companies locking down IAM for security reasons.

Comment: Besides this will work only for some time if accessKeyId and secretAccessKey rotate.

Answer (score 35):

I made the connection using a different approach:

```
BasicAWSCredentials credentials = new BasicAWSCredentials(ACCESS_KEY, SECRET_KEY);
AmazonDynamoDBClient client = new AmazonDynamoDBClient(credentials).withRegion(Regions.US_EAST_1);
DynamoDB dynamoDB = new DynamoDB(client);
```

The access key and the secret key can be created in the [Identity and Access Management](https://console.aws.amazon.com/iam/home#home) console. I hope it helps...

Answer (score 34):

You can use `DefaultAwsCredentialsProviderChain()`, which according to the [documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/auth/DefaultAWSCredentialsProviderChain.html), looks for credentials in this order:

1. Environment Variables - `AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID` and `AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY` (**recommended** since they are recognized by all AWS SDKs and CLI except for .NET), or `AWS_ACCESS_KEY` and `AWS_SECRET_KEY` (only recognized by the Java SDK)
2. Java System Properties - `aws.accessKeyId` and `aws.secretAccessKey`
3. Credential profiles file at the default location (`~/.aws/credentials`) shared by all AWS SDKs and the AWS CLI
4. Instance profile credentials delivered through the Amazon EC2 metadata service

Answer (score 13):

```
AWSCredentialsProvider credentialsProvider = new ProfileCredentialsProvider();
new AmazonEC2Client(credentialsProvider)
```

.aws/credentials

```
[default]
aws_access_key_id =
aws_secret_access_key =
```

Comment: Looking at your answer, i figured aws_access_key_id and aws_secret_access_key -> must be all lower case, that solved my issue

Answer (score 8):

Try this for the file format:

```
[default]
aws_access_key_id=<your access key>
aws_secret_access_key=<your secret access key>
```

I saved this file as ~/.aws/credentials with ProfileCredentialsProvider().

Comment: Where to put this file?

Comment: @Arslan, put this file in `<local_drive>/.aws/` folder. Like my file is located at `C:\Users\Abhishek\.aws` location. Full path `C:\Users\Abhishek\.aws\credentials`. Also, when I installed the AWS plugin in eclipse it gave me a popup to fill the **Access Key** and **Secret Access Key** and created **credentials** file automatically at `C:\Users\Abhishek\.aws\credentials` location

Comment: I did not have a new line after the aws_secret_access_key line. This works on other AWS API library but not with the Client Side Monitoring. Be aware.

Comment: I was using Eclipse from my local machine and installing AWS Toolkit for Eclipse helped got past the error.

Comment: This will work only for some time if the accessKeyId and secretAccessKey rotate.

Answer (score 4):

If you are using Java and Springboot and want to do it in the code, the below configuration will work.

When building EC2 Client, Add the Credential Provider

```
 Region region = Region.US_EAST_1;
 Ec2Client ec2 = Ec2Client.builder()
            .httpClientBuilder(new DefaultSdkHttpClientBuilder())
            .credentialsProvider(SystemPropertyCredentialsProvider.create())
            .region(region)
            .build();
```

In the Application Start up,

```
@Value("${aws.accessKeyId}")
private String accessKey;

@Value("${aws.secretKey}")
private String secretKey;

@PostConstruct
public void setSystemProperty(){
    SystemPropertiesCredentialsProvider systemPropertiesCredentialsProvider=new SystemPropertiesCredentialsProvider();

    System.setProperty("aws.accessKeyId",accessKey);
    System.setProperty("aws.secretAccessKey",secretKey);
}
```

In application.properties file,

```
aws.accessKeyId=
aws.secretKey=
```

Answer (score 3):

In my case I was deploying my webapp inside a docker. I was setting:

```
ENV AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=blahblah%&/(
ENV AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=supersecret%&/(
```

but I still got errors, I got fixed this by adding

```
cloud.aws.credentials.useDefaultAwsCredentialsChain=true
```

inside `application.properties`

Answer (score 2):

If you use the credential file at ~/.aws/credentials and use the default profile as below:

```
[default]
aws_access_key_id=<your access key>
aws_secret_access_key=<your secret access key>
```

You do not need to use `BasicAWSCredential` or `AWSCredentialsProvider`. The SDK can pick up the credentials from the default profile, just by initializing the client object with the default constructor. Example below:

```
AmazonEC2Client ec2Client = new AmazonEC2Client();
```

In addition sometime you would need to initialize the client with the ClientConfiguration to provide proxy settings etc. Example below.

```
ClientConfiguration clientConfiguration = new ClientConfiguration();
clientConfiguration.setProxyHost("proxyhost");
clientConfiguration.setProxyPort(proxyport);
AmazonEC2Client ec2Client = new AmazonEC2Client(clientConfiguration);
```

Comment: Thank you. Commenting out `.withCredentials(new InstanceProfileCredentialsProvider(false))` on my Client did the trick.

Answer (score 2):

Since AmazonDynamoDBClient(credentials) is deprecated i use this.

```
init {
        val cp= AWSStaticCredentialsProvider(BasicAWSCredentials(ACCESS_KEY, SECRET_KEY))
        val client = AmazonDynamoDBClientBuilder.standard().withCredentials(cp).withRegion(Regions.US_EAST_1).build()
        dynamoDB = DynamoDB(client)
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're wanting to use Environment variables using apache/tomcat, I found
that the only way they could be found was setting them in tomcat/bin/setenv.sh
(where catalina_opts are set - might be catalina.sh in your setup)

export AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=*********;

export AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=**************;

If you're using ubuntu, try logging in as ubuntu $printenv then log in as root $printenv,
the environmental variables won't necessarily be the same....

If you only want to use environmental variables you can use:
com.amazonaws.auth.EnvironmentVariableCredentialsProvider

instead of:

com.amazonaws.auth.DefaultAWSCredentialsProviderChain

(which by default checks all 4 possible locations)

anyway after hours of trying to figure out why my environmental variables weren't being found...this worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

Example java code:

```
        //DATA//
        //get from: https://console.aws.amazon.com/iam/home?#/security_credentials -> Access keys (access key ID and secret access key) -> Generate key if not exists
        String accessKey;
        String secretKey;
        Regions region = Regions.AP_SOUTH_1; //get from "https://ap-south-1.console.aws.amazon.com/lambda/" > your function > ARN at top right
        
        //CODE//
        AWSLambda awsLambda = AWSLambdaClientBuilder.standard()
                .withCredentials(new AWSStaticCredentialsProvider(new BasicAWSCredentials(accessKey, secretKey)))
                .withRegion(region)
                .build();

        List<FunctionConfiguration> functionList= awsLambda.listFunctions().getFunctions();
        for (FunctionConfiguration functConfig : functionList) {
           System.out.println("FunctionName="+functConfig.getFunctionName());
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

**You can access your credantials with this code If you already signed in to AWS CLI.**

```
  DefaultAWSCredentialsProviderChain props = new DefaultAWSCredentialsProviderChain();

  AWSCredentials credentials = props.getCredentials();

  final String AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID = credentials.getAWSAccessKeyId();
  final String AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY = credentials.getAWSSecretKey();
```

Answer (score 0):

In a Linux server, using default implementation of `ses` will expect files in `.aws/credentials` file. You can put following content in credential file at the location below and it will work. `/home/local/<your service account>/.aws/credentials`.

```
[default]
aws_access_key_id=<your access key>
aws_secret_access_key=<your secret access key>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many correct answer above. 
Specifically in Windows, when you don't have ~/.aws/ folder exist and you need to create the new one, it turned out to be another problem, meaning if you just type "**.aws**" as name, it will error out and will not allow you create the folder with name ".aws".

Here is trick to overcome that, i.e. type in **".aws."** meaning **dot at the start and dot at the end**. Then only windows will accept the name. This has happened with me, so providing an answer here. SO that it may be helpful to others.

Answer (score 0):

A java program to set AWS environment vairiable.

```
Map<String, String> environment = new HashMap<String, String>();
        environment.put("AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID", "*****************");
        environment.put("AWS_SECRET_KEY", "*************************");

private static void setEnv(Map<String, String> newenv) throws Exception {
        try {
            Class<?> processEnvironmentClass = Class.forName("java.lang.ProcessEnvironment");
            Field theEnvironmentField = processEnvironmentClass.getDeclaredField("theEnvironment");
            theEnvironmentField.setAccessible(true);
            Map<String, String> env = (Map<String, String>) theEnvironmentField.get(null);
            env.putAll(newenv);
            Field theCaseInsensitiveEnvironmentField = processEnvironmentClass.getDeclaredField("theCaseInsensitiveEnvironment");
            theCaseInsensitiveEnvironmentField.setAccessible(true);
            Map<String, String> cienv = (Map<String, String>) theCaseInsensitiveEnvironmentField.get(null);
            cienv.putAll(newenv);
        } catch (NoSuchFieldException e) {
            Class[] classes = Collections.class.getDeclaredClasses();
            Map<String, String> env = System.getenv();
            for (Class cl : classes) {
                if ("java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableMap".equals(cl.getName())) {
                    Field field = cl.getDeclaredField("m");
                    field.setAccessible(true);
                    Object obj = field.get(env);
                    Map<String, String> map = (Map<String, String>) obj;
                    map.clear();
                    map.putAll(newenv);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was way sillier - I changed the system time to test run and trigger a cron job. The mismatch between system time and AWS's other components caused the issue.