# AWS Instance creation error

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ec2-ami, ec2-api-tools

i am getting the below error while creating an instance in AWS through eclipse.

```
exception in thread "main" com.amazonaws.AmazonClientException: Unable to load AWS credentials from any provider in the chain
    at com.amazonaws.auth.AWSCredentialsProviderChain.getCredentials(AWSCredentialsProviderChain.java:117)
    at com.amazonaws.services.opsworks.AWSOpsWorksClient.invoke(AWSOpsWorksClient.java:3574)
    at com.amazonaws.services.opsworks.AWSOpsWorksClient.createInstance(AWSOpsWorksClient.java:2098)
    at AwsConsoleApp.main(AwsConsoleApp.java:154)
```

my code reads:

```
String az=new String("ec2.us-east-1.amazonaws.com");
cir.setAvailabilityZone(az);
String ami_id=new String("ami-864d84ee");
cir.setAmiId(ami_id);
CreateInstanceResult cr=awoc.createInstance(cir);
```

please hep me on this.

Comment: see if this helps http://stackoverflow.com/a/22722293/1043824

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you need to provide your credentials to access your AWS account:

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSdkDocsJava/latest/DeveloperGuide/credentials.html

Comment: What if I want to access amazon resource anonymously which is public available? How to provide "anonymous" credentials?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. You should ask a new question.