# Unable to load AWS credentials from any provider in the chain -> [Help 1] eclipse/intellij while mvn install

Tags: eclipse, amazon-web-services, intellij-idea, amazon-iam, aws-java-sdk

I have imported mvn project while have external s3 dependencies, while building application I am getting below error:

Unable to load AWS credentials from any provider in the chain -> [Help 1]

I have tried multiple solutions(re-import, cloned fresh copy) and below once are settings on my system

C:\Users<user_name>\Documents>aws configure list
Name                    Value             Type    Location
----                    -----             ----    --------
profile                             None    None
access_key     ******************SY shared-credentials-file
secret_key     ******************8r shared-credentials-file
region                us-west-2      config-file    ~/.aws/config

2. I have my credentials file in path ==>  C:\Users<user_name>.aws

Still I am getting same error on both the IDE.
Please help to solve this.

Comment: What is the full error. Please include it and screenshots. How does command line Maven build work?

Comment: using mvn install command to build service...

full Error :

Failed to execute goal on project iot_service: Could not resolve dependencies for project com.hp:iot_service:jar:1.0.1: Failed to collect dependencies at com.job-processor:jar:0.1.7 -> com.service-sdk:jar:0.0.55: Failed to read artifact descriptor for com.service-sdk:jar:0.0.55: Could not transfer artifact com.service-sdk:pom:0.0.55 from/to maven-s3-release (s3://java-libraries/release): Unable to load AWS credentials from any provider in the chain -> [Help 1]

Comment: See https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-java/issues/1324#issuecomment-333645451 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/22722293/2000323

Answer (score 1):

Put your key and secret key in a file named credentials located here:

[image]

For those new to AWS Java V2, see this new quick start that is intended to get you up and running very fast: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/latest/developer-guide/get-started.html